# superfast ssd (PCIe connector) to MBP mid2012?

Tags: macbook-pro

is it possible to put one of these new generation ssd to my MBP with pci express connector?

[PCIe SSD](http://www.computerweekly.com/feature/PCIe-SSD-What-it-is-and-how-you-can-use-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2013 MacBook Air is already using PCIe and has been tested to reach 800MB/second.

I don't think any of the other MacBooks are using PCIe yet, but since the Air is Apple's slowest mac, it's likely everything will be using PCIe soon.

For an older MacBook Pro, you won't be able to add a PCIe drive but you will get pretty close to the same performance if you buy a good SSD. Some of them can do 500MB/s.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible as the Macbook Pro 2012 doesn't come with a PCIe according to the Apple specifications.

http://support.apple.com/kb/sp649

You can put a standard aftermarket SATA SSD in though.